# how to create dynamic stages in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, python, groovy, pipeline

I want to use a python script as input to create stages in jenkins pipeline

test.py

```py
{'job-name': 'Test1', 'action': 'a', 'targetname': 'x'}
{'job-name': 'Test2', 'action': 'b', 'targetname': 'y'} 
{'job-name': 'Test3', 'action': 'c', 'targetname': 'z'}
```

The output of the above python script is a dictionary.

How to run this python script in Jenkins pipeline in a stage and how to store the output and use the output to define further stages

Example:

```
stage(Test1) {

}
stage(Test2) {

}
stage(Test3) {

}
```

Extract only 'value' of a particular 'key' from the output of python script to define stages in Jenkins pipeline.

How to execute it in Jenkins groovy as declarative pipeline ?

Comment: Did you solve your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This was already [asked and answered over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837066/can-i-create-dynamically-stages-in-a-jenkins-pipeline).

TL;DR: you must use Scripted Pipeline; Declarative does not support dynamic stages.  Here is a copy-paste of the top answer:

> Use the scripted syntax that allows more flexibility than the
> declarative syntax, even though the declarative is more documented and
> recommended.
>
> For example stages can be created in a loop:
>
> ```
> def tests = params.Tests.split(',')
> for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
>     stage("Test ${tests[i]}") {
>         sh '....'
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: is this file complete or would you need to wrap this in a `stages` block?

Comment: It would need to be wrapped in a `script { }` block.